# How to call Mage_Page_Block_Html_Pager class in list.phtml

Tags: magento-1.7, template, model, pagination, class

I am wanting to include a larger than normal 'next page' type button in the list.phtml template whilst still having the normal pagination from pager.phtml

The function I'm wanting to use is found in code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Pager.php:

```
public function getNextPageUrl()
    {
        return $this->getPageUrl($this->getCollection()->getCurPage(+1));
    }
```

This can be called in pager.phtml by performing $this->getNextPageUrl(). I'm wanting to call this function inside list.phtml but I'm not sure how to get it. Using $this->getNextPageUrl() doesn't work.

I've also tried variations of Mage::getModel('page/html_pager')->getNextPageUrl() without luck.

Comment: Did you try `Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_pager')->getNextPageUrl()`?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways of doing this. One is slightly easier than the other.

**Add After `getToolbarHtml` call**

If you do it after the call to `getToolbarHtml` in the list.phtml then the following code will work.

```
<?php echo $this->getChild('product_list_toolbar')->getChild('product_list_toolbar_pager')->getNextPageUrl() ?>
```

This is because the pager is actually inside the toolbar and not the list, see layout xml.

```
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
    <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
        <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
```

And most importantly the collection is setup in the toolbar's `getPagerHtml` function:

```
public function getPagerHtml()
{
    $pagerBlock = $this->getChild('product_list_toolbar_pager');

    if ($pagerBlock instanceof Varien_Object) {

        /* @var $pagerBlock Mage_Page_Block_Html_Pager */
        $pagerBlock->setAvailableLimit($this->getAvailableLimit());

        $pagerBlock->setUseContainer(false)
            ->setShowPerPage(false)
            ->setShowAmounts(false)
            ->setLimitVarName($this->getLimitVarName())
            ->setPageVarName($this->getPageVarName())
            ->setLimit($this->getLimit())
            ->setFrameLength(Mage::getStoreConfig('design/pagination/pagination_frame'))
            ->setJump(Mage::getStoreConfig('design/pagination/pagination_frame_skip'))
            ->setCollection($this->getCollection());

        return $pagerBlock->toHtml();
    }

    return '';
}
```

**Add before `getToolbarHtml` call**

Or if you simply want to put it anywhere in the template what you can do is set the collection using the list`s collection with the following code.

```
$productCollection = $this->getLoadedProductCollection();
$pagerBlock = $this->getChild('product_list_toolbar')->getChild('product_list_toolbar_pager');
$pagerBlock->setCollection($productCollection);
echo $pagerBlock->getNextPageUrl();
```

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the url you need. Simple as that. Works in category list pages and search results pages (advanced and quick):

```
$nextPage = $this
           ->getChild('toolbar')
           ->getChild('product_list_toolbar_pager')
           ->getPageUrl($_productCollection->getCurPage(+1));
```

Just make sure you use ti after this line:

```
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give the URL of the next page, But when you will reach last page in pagination, it will show second last page means previous to last.

```
$productCollection = $this->getLoadedProductCollection();
$pagerBlock = $this->getChild('product_list_toolbar')->getChild('product_list_toolbar_pager');
$pagerBlock->setCollection($productCollection);
 echo $current_url = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
 $nextpageurl = $pagerBlock->getNextPageUrl();
 $prevpageurl = $pagerBlock->getPreviousPageUrl();
 if(strcmp($nextpageurl) == strcmp($current_url)){     
 echo $prevpageurl;
 }
 else{
echo  $nextpageurl = $pagerBlock->getNextPageUrl();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on it for last day and find a way by which you can use the code anywhere in the product collection view to get the next page URL.

```
$productCollection = $this->getLoadedProductCollection();

echo $nextPage = $this->getChild('toolbar')->getChild('product_list_toolbar_pager') ->getPageUrl($productCollection->getCurPage(+1));
```

Comment: isn't this exactly what I just said?